# Adobe Illustrator - Blend Inner and outer line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, blending

I am using Adobe Illustrator; I have these two shapes: outer and inner, and I want to repeat them in between.

I tried offset path with miter and they didn't matc;, the corners were starting to get round.

Also I tried blending them but got an undesirable effect.

Any idea how I can solve this?[image: r]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I am using Illustrator

Comment: The blend should work.. there's simply a problem with one or both of the original paths around that center shape. (Note how the blend is find everywhere else) Make certain *both* paths have the same number of anchor points in relative positions.

Comment: Yes, i understand, but still the blending has issues because even in the areas that looks good is not. The repeated lines are out of the original two lines.

Comment: Did you try reducing the blend steps? Or creating a middle path as an intermediate blend step?

Comment: Yes i did, for sure the main problem was reduced when i double check the number of anchor points, but there are some areas, that the middle line, that now i have is not following properly the other two lines.

Comment: Offset does not generally do a line that is well behaved for blending. If you must do this then offset and counter offset this should give you a slightly better target but not a good target by any means.

Comment: I think you may be asking too much from automation while desiring specific results. There are many projects where the only option is manual creation of paths.